# ThreadlocalRandom and just Random

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I'm reading a java 8 book by Richard Warburton and have a question about random number genereation for parallel streams. Here's the two-dice-throw simulation example he provided:

```
public Map<Integer, Double> parallelDiceRolls(){
    double fraction = 1.0/N;
    return IntStream.range(0, N)
                     .parallel()
                     .mapToObj(twoDiceThrows())
                     .collect(groupingby(side -> side, 
                               summingDouble(n -> fracton));
```

My question is about the `twoDiceThrow` function. Later on he gives its *sketch*:

```
private int twoDiceThrow(ThreadLocalRandom random){
    int firstThrow = random.nextInt(1, 7);
    int secindThrow = random.nextInt(1, 7);
    return firstThrow + secondThrow;
}
```

The question here is about `ThreadLocalRandom`. Doesn't it hurt the statistic? I mean `ThreadLocalRandom` is confined to a `Thread` and since we process our stream in parallel one thread doing the job knows nothing about results produced by the other. Therefore the statistic might differ from one that would be aggregated with `Random` and `synchronization`.

Comment: The statistics would also be different when you run the code multiple times. That's the point of a *Random* number generator. It would matter if you were providing a fixed seed to the pseudo random number generator.

Comment: *The question here is* how do you expect that code to compile? `mapToObj(twoDiceThrows())` won't compile, because `mapToObj()` expects an `IntFunction`, i.e. a method with an `int` parameter, and `twoDiceThrows()` does not return such an `IntFunction`. Perhaps it wasn't meant as a method *call*, but a method *reference*, i.e. without the parenthesis, but that still wouldn't work, because the method doesn't take an `int` parameter.

Comment: @Andreas Maybe `twoDiceThrows` and `twoDiceThrow` are two different methods ... (the first not shown here)? But maybe it is a simple typo, and your comment is valid ...

Comment: [Random number generator](http://assets.amuniversal.com/321a39e06d6401301d80001dd8b71c47)

Comment: It makes no sense to receive a `ThreadLocalRandom` instance as parameter, as there is only one valid instance for a particular execution context, the one returned by `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`…

Comment: @Holger I dind't show the rest of the code as it's quite large. But the author assumes that we use the instance of `ThreadLocalRandom` in a single thread.

Comment: The caller might pass the correct instance, that’s not the point. It simply makes no sense to create a parameter for something, for which only a single correct value (object) exists. Parameters suggest a choice, which simply doesn’t exist here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence of values generated from a Random should be uncorrelated.

Similarly the sequence of values generated from a ThreadLocalRandom should be uncorrelated with values from itself, and values from any other ThreadLocalRandom with a different seed.

So switching to `ThreadLocalRandom` should give values with the same statistics as using `Random`.

The advantage is that you avoid any need for synchronization.

Comment: So the "degree of randomness" is percisely the same, isn't? Does it mean that in `ThreadLocalRandom` is a preffered choice since it was introduced?